# How do I make IntelliJ ignore javascript syntax errors in one .js file?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, intellij-14

In my IntelliJ project I have this file:

```
MyMvnModule\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\Owasp.csrfguard.js
```

This file contains these placeholders that are filled in by a servlet at run time:

```
} else if(%DOMAIN_STRICT% == false) {
...
}
```

IntelliJ sees that `%DOMAIN_STRICT%` is a syntax error which causes it to angry red underline every folder in the path to that file. Is there a way to keep intelliJ from syntax checking this one file so that this doesn't happen?

Comment: Does this help? https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/changing-highlighting-level-for-the-current-file.html

Comment: @thatidiotguy, that is exactly what I needed. Thanks. If you want to post that below, I'll accept it as the best answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To [change the highlighting level](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#change-highlighting-level-for-file) for the current file:

1. Open the **Highlighting Level** pop-up window by doing one of the following:

   - On the main menu, choose **Analyze | Configure Current File Analysis**.
   - Press **Ctrl+Shift+Alt+H**.
   - Click the *Hector* icon on the status bar (bottom right-hand corner).
   - Right-click the code inspection indicator at the top of the scroll bar. Choose **Customize Highlighting Level**.
2. Move the slider to one of the three available positions that define the highlighting level:

   - **None**: turn highlighting off.
   - **Syntax**: highlight syntax problems only.
   - **Inspections**: (default) highlight syntax problems and problems found by inspections.

Answer (score 0):

I use this way:
  - right click the file
  - select "mark as plain text"

Then it will not check anything in that file. I use this with some lib.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line above the error line

// noinspection JSAnnotator